# RxJava: Execute second observables only if first one throws an error and repeat from the first

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I am using `retorift` to hit `getAricle` api and get list of articles related to the user. `getArticle` api will throw error if token passed is expired if so then I have to call `refreshToken` api to get new token then again I have to call the `getArticle` api

```
 ApiController.createRx().getArticle(token)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ response -> toast(response.body().url) }, { e ->
                println(e.printStackTrace())
                if(e is HttpException && e.code() in  arrayOf(401,403)){                      
                   //Here I want to call refresh tolken api
                   toast("Auth error")
                }
                else
                   toast(R.string.something_went_wrong)
            })
```

**Edit**

Even though given answers showed some direction but those are not a direct answer to my question. This is how solved it but I feel this can be refactored into much better code

```
ApiController.createRx().getArticle(Preference.getToken())
            .flatMap { value ->
                if (value.code() in arrayOf(403, 401)) {
                    ApiController.refreshToken()
                    ApiController.createRx().getArticle(Preference.getToken())
                } else Observable.just(value)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ response -> println("Success") }, { e ->
                e.printStackTrace()
                toast(R.string.something_went_wrong)
            })



fun refreshToken() {
        val token:String?=ApiController.createRx().refreshToken(Preferences.getRefreshToken()).blockingFirst()?.body()?.token
        if (token != null) Preferences.setAuthToken(token)
    }
```

**EDIT**

I refactored my code to little more cleaner version

```
Observable.defer { ApiController.createRx().getArticle(Preferences.getToken()) }
            .flatMap {
                if (it.code() in arrayOf(401, 403)) {
                    ApiController.refreshToken()
                    Observable.error(Throwable())
                } else Observable.just(it)
            }
            .retry(1)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({println("Success") }, {
              it.printStackTrace()
              toast(R.string.something_went_wrong)
            })



 fun refreshToken() {
        var token: String? = null
        try {
            token = createRx().refreshToken(Preferences.getRefreshToken()).blockingFirst().body()!!.token
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
        println("saving token")
        if (token != null) Preferences.setAuthToken(token)
    }
```

**EDIT**

Please check my answer for the final refactored code

Comment: First of all, with retrofit you can avoid going directly to `onError`. You can return `Single<Result<CustomObject>>` which never returns error. But if you want to keep getting `onError` try using the error handling operators of RxJava [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)

Comment: @masp In both the scenario I am not able get my head around how to recall getArticle api. Can you please show me how to do that

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Were any of the answers provided helpful? If so, please consider upvoting any helpful answers, and if one of them led you to a solution, accepting that answer.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer Hey I am able to solve it after spending some time And I wrote it as answer Please comment your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after reading more about `RxJava` and this is how I implemented it.
First of all will `retrofit` throw 4xx error to `onError` or `onNext\onSuccess` depends on how we define it.
Ex:

`@GET("content")
 fun getArticle(@Header("Authorization") token: String):Single<Article>`

this will throw all the 4xx errors to `onError` and instead of `Single<Article>` if you define it as `Single<Response<Article>>` then all the response from server including 4xx will go to `onNext\onSuccess`

```
Single.defer { ApiController.createRx().getArticle(Preferences.getAuthToken())}
                .doOnError {
                    if (it is HttpException && it.code() == 401)
                        ApiController.refreshToken()
                }
                .retry { attempts, error -> attempts < 3 && error is HttpException && error.code() == 401 }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({println("Success") }, {
                  it.printStackTrace()
                  toast(R.string.something_went_wrong)
                })
```

I am using `defer` as a wrapper around my actual `Observable` because I want to recreate the article fetch observable on retry after token refresh because I want `Preferences.getAuthToken()` to be called again as my refresh token code stores newly fetched token in preference.

`retry` returns true if the `HttpException` is 401 and not attempted retry more than 2 times

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this exact thing. Here is a slightly modified version of that code:

```
private Observable<Object> refreshTokenIfNotAuthorized(Observable<? extends Throwable> errors) {
    final AtomicBoolean alreadyRetried = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    return errors.flatMap(error -> {

        boolean isAuthorizationError = /* some logic analyzing each error*/ ;

        if (isAuthorizationError && !alreadyRetried.get()) {
            try {
                alreadyRetried.set(true);
                String newToken = federatedTokenRefresher.refreshToken()
                                                         .toBlocking()
                                                         .first();

                setLogin(newToken);
                return Observable.just(null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Observable.error(error);
            }

        }
        return Observable.error(error);
    });
}
```

You can use this method like so:

```
doSomethingRequiringAuth().retryWhen(this::refreshTokenIfNotAuthorized);
```

Comment: @Praveen I agree that your solution works, but as you say, not exactly elegant. Is there something in my proposal that doesn't meet your need? If so, what is it?

Comment: at first I thought retrofit throwing all the 4xx errors to `onError` later I realized it is only network error which was directly going to `onError` so then `retryWhen` will not work. I had to use `flatMap` only. In your code how do you unsubscribe from this `federatedTokenRefresher.refreshToken()
                                                         .toBlocking()
                                                         .first()`

Comment: You don't need to subscribe/unsubscribe when you call `toBlocking`.

Comment: What happens if I close the app in the middle of that blocking call?

Comment: If by "close" you mean put in the background, it keeps running. Of course you should unsubscribe the UI as part of your lifecycle handling. As for your question about handling network errors - I would suggest you put another `retryWhen` operator in your chain before `.retryWhen(this::refreshTokenIfNotAuthorized)` and handle network errors there. Also in general, if the operation you're trying to perform is composed of multiple API calls, it might be easier to just ask the user to retry if there is a network error.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error you will received?. It´s seems like you could use `onErrorResumeNext` operator.

This operator once that receive a throwable, allow you to return an Observable instead the throwable in the onError

```
@Test
    public void observableOnErrorResumeException() {
        Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        Observable.from(numbers)
                .doOnNext(number -> {
                    if (number > 3) {
                        try {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }

                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.just(666))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

    }
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/errors/ObservableExceptions.java

Comment: then how do you repeat after procesing error and refreshing the token

Comment: You can use retryWhen operator, look the rest of examples that I paste you in the link

Answer (score 0):

I will give you another option using groupBy operator

```
/**
 * In this example we create a response code group.
 */
@Test
public void testGroupByCode() {
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList(401,403, 200))
            .groupBy(code -> code)
            .subscribe(groupByCode -> {
                switch (groupByCode.getKey()) {
                    case 401: {
                        System.out.println("refresh token");
                        processResponse(groupByCode);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 403: {
                        System.out.println("refresh token");
                        processResponse(groupByCode);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        System.out.println("Do the toast");
                        processResponse(groupByCode);
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void processResponse(GroupedObservable<Integer, Integer> groupByCode) {
    groupByCode.asObservable().subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Response code:" + value));
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand this. This is too generic. How to apply this to my scenario and there is also no `asObservable` in Rx java2. And where are you re trying original observable after refreshing the token

Comment: Take a look to the groupby operator in the documentation

Comment: I know `groupBy` operator but how to apply that to my scenario

Comment: As I did in my answer, your group contains the value of the response and also the observable. If it's 401-403 create a new observable with the refresh and the default just subscribe

Comment: Not saying is better than your original solution by the way. Just different ;)

Comment: Hey I solved my problem after spending some time on RxJava Please check my answer and please give me suggestion if something is not right in that